# how to add dynamically new rows in table control in wpf...?

Tags: c#, wpf

`FlowDocumentScrollViewer` inside this control i used Table and rows,But I want dynamically rows in run time and also when i click enter Key then save records into database and one new row add in this table.

Q (1)Is It Possible...?

if Yes Then Please help.

code here:

```
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>                               
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>F9,F1 P.R.C</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>O.A No</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>O.A SI</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Heat No</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Pour Date</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Grade</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Product</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>W.I.P</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Heat Treat</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Final Clearance</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Fett</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="50"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="50"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="30"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="30"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <TextBox Width="30"></TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableRowGroup>
                    </Table>
                </FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Please See Image Of my Code [OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMEyi.png):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I demonstrated how you can add rows to a table row with a simple application. First we need some xaml code:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Table Name="tblDummyData">
                    <TableRowGroup>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="1.1" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="1.2" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="1.3" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="2.1" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="2.2" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="2.3" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="3.1" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="3.2" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="3.3" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="4.1" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="4.2" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <TextBlock Text="4.3" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableRowGroup>
                </Table>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>

        <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see nothing special here, just a table with bunch of rows and cells and a button for adding rows.

So here is what lays behind this code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rowGroup = tblDummyData.RowGroups.FirstOrDefault();

        if (rowGroup != null)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();

            TableCell cell = new TableCell();

            cell.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("New Cell 1")));
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("New cell 2")));
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("New cell 3")));
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            rowGroup.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Here you can see how to define a table Row than populate it with as much cells as you need and append it to your row group. In my case I have only one row group but you can query them with linq and get whichewer row group you need.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How can I add Textbox using Button_Click please. Like instead of "New cell 1" I want to add TextBox